# How Jelastic "internal" load balancer check nodes health?

Tags: jelastic

As far as I understand, Jelastic utilizes some kind of load balancer which is deployed behind the nodes.
So if I have two nodes and one node is down, how this load balancer will act?
I'm thinking about blue-green deployment without traffic distributor add-on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, all the incoming traffic at Jelastic Platform is routed between containers via [Shared Load Balancer](https://docs.jelastic.com/shared-load-balancer). Herewith, this node performs constant servers’ health checkups, utilizing the [*NGINX upstream check module*](https://github.com/yaoweibin/nginx_upstream_check_module) with the following settings for that:

*interval=15000 rise=2 fall=3 timeout=2000 default_down=false;*

In such a way, all containers are considered “up” from the startup, whilst the system verifies their availability each 15 seconds. If no response is received from a container within 2 seconds, such checkup is regarded as failed. Three consecutive fails will mark a node as “down”, whilst two successful checks in a row - as “up”.

As for the traffic distribution within a separate environment, a dedicated load balancer node is automatically added to its topology when the number of application server instances is set more than one (i.e. it’s scaled out [horizontally](https://docs.jelastic.com/app-server-scaling)). Jelastic PaaS provides 4 load balancer stacks you can choose between, each of which has some health check configuration specifics:

**NGINX** - runs a simple tcp check (i.e. verifies the required server port availability) right before routing a user request to it; if the check fails, the next node within a layer will be tried

**HAProxy** - performs regular tcp checks (every 2 seconds by default), storing the results in a table of backends state and keeping it constantly up-to-date

**Apache Balancer** - no implemented health check procedure by default

**Varnish** - all backends are assigned the *probe = { .url = "/"; .timeout = 30s; .interval = 60s; .window = 5; .threshold = 2; }* parameter within balancer configs, so that the health checks are performed once per minute with a 30 seconds timeout (see the [official documentation](http://varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/BackendPolling?version=5) for more information)

Obviously, the default health check settings can be manually adjusted up to your needs (through either Jelastic [File Manager](https://docs.jelastic.com/application-configuration) GUI or via [SSH](https://docs.jelastic.com/ssh-access)) according to the appropriate load balancer stack specification - refer to the official [NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/http-health-check/), [HAProxy](https://www.haproxy.com/doc/aloha/7.0/haproxy/healthchecks.html), [Apache Balancer](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy_hcheck.html) or [Varnish](http://varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/BackendPolling?version=5) documentation to see the details on possible settings.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple web application nodes (e.g. Apache servers) you should also add your own load balancer node (in which case you have control over the health check parameters in Nginx or Apache configs).

It's also highly recommended to use public IPs for production use. Only use the Jelastic shared resolvers / load balancers for proxying requests to your environment during dev/test (they're shared infrastructure, so can be a bottleneck for your application as well as introducing other bugs / unwanted behaviours re. headers, protocols, ciphers etc.).

Comment: So the answer is "internal load balancer does simple round-robin and doesn't performs any health-checks", right?

Comment: Not really. Excluding Docker nodes (where you make your own arrangements regarding topology structure etc) Jelastic automatically adds a dedicated load balancer node to your environment. "Shared load balancer" does not really do "load balancing" so there's no LB algorithms or health checks in that sense.

Comment: >Jelastic automatically adds a dedicated load balancer node

So I'm curious how this thing works if I'll add node and will have 2 nodes of same container in my env

Comment: It depends which type of load balancer node you add (e.g. nginx, Apache, HAProxy) and how you configure it (you have access to config)

Comment: I don't add load balancer node. I'm asking 'bout "default" load balancer (probably "shared" one in jelastic terms)

Comment: Please update your question with a screenshot of your environment to clarify this point.